# listviewをスクロールしてtitlebarを隠したい

Tags: android, scrollview

やりたいことはこれ
https://github.com/rkowase/android-bottom-navigation-custom-behavior-sample

真ん中にいれるのは、listviewです。

いろいろと調べましたところ
CoordinatorLayout と、nestscrollview を使う方法で簡単にできたのですが
この方法だと、scrollviewの中に、listviewを入れることになってしまいました。
また、動作が少しおかしい感じがしました。

scrollviewを使わないで、listviewだけで
上記のように上と下のバーを隠すことは出来ないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

ListViewにリスナを設定してスクロールを検出することで力技で解決できなくもないとは思いますが…